# Quisiera poner el .text del print directamente en la búsqueda de las etiquetas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hola quisiera saber si podría hacer el .text directamente en la variable sin tener que hacerlo en el print, como por ejemplo

price = child_soup.find('h3',class_ = 'font-medium text-midnight text-3xl mb-1b').text

. Ya que luego quisiera modificar esas variables y tal cual como esta el código las variables al ser extraídas de la pagina son la etiqueta mas el texto

```
for i in soup_list:
href = i.find (href = True)

cleaned_href = i['href']
print (cleaned_href)
sub_url = 'https://housfy.com' + cleaned_href
sub_page = requests.get(sub_url)
child_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_page.content, 'html.parser')
price = child_soup.find('h3',class_ = 'font-medium text-midnight text-3xl mb-1b')
surface = child_soup.select('div.mb-2>span')[0]
n_rooms = child_soup.select('div.mb-2>span')[2]
n_bathrooms = child_soup.select('div.mb-2>span')[4]
sub_menu = child_soup.find_all ('div', class_= 'flex flex-wrap flex-1 items-center mb-1')
for i in sub_menu:
    construction_year = sub_menu[0].find ('span', class_='text-midnight')
    orientation = sub_menu[3].find ('span', class_='text-midnight')
print (price.text, surface.text, n_rooms.text, n_bathrooms.text, construction_year.text, orientation.text)

break
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Has probado borrar los `print()`? Normalmente se usan para que el usuario o el programador vea lo que hay dentro de las variables, no son necesarios para asignar un `string` a una variable.

Comment: perdona, me he equivocado.
Es trantando de quitar los.text del print

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta para mostrar que ese es tu objetivo por favor? Por que tal como está das a entender otra cosa. Por cierto, podrías crear tu propia función para no tener que poner .text a cada rato.